# Numbers arranged around a Circle

Tags: combinatorics

The Numbers $1,2,\dots,12$ are arranged in a circle in that order.
In how many ways can five numbers
be chosen from this arrangement so that no two adjacent numbers are selected?

I can't think of a good way to think about this problem. I tried picking a random number and looking at the numbers that are possible, but there are cases where the $2$ numbers are just seperated by $1$ number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each configuration 5/12 of the numbers are chosen, so 5/12 of the possibilities will include the number $1$. Let's concentrate on these.

There are five gaps between numbers, adding to a total of $7$, and none of the gaps can be zero - so $1+1+1+1+3$ or $1+1+1+2+2$. The first gives $5$ ways of choosing the remaining four numbers (the gap of $3$ can be in one of five places). The second gives [?] ways.

There are therefore [?] possibilities which include the number $1$ and hence [?] altogether.

Comment: Sorry, but wht cant the gaps1 1 1 1 2,isnt 1 gap enough? Your answer is correct (36)

Comment: Csn you please clarify the 1st sentence of rhe 2nd paragraph

Comment: @SuperMage1 The total of gaps plus the total number of places filled has to be $12$ (a number is chosen, or it lies in a gap). If there are five places filled, there are five gaps (eg the gap to the left of each place). Numbers are adjacent if and only if the gap between them is zero, so there are no gaps of length zero by the condition, and the total length of gaps is seven.

Comment: ok thanks i fully understand it now

Answer (score 0):

Start with the most basic configuration:
$$1,3,5,7,9$$
If we rotate this configuration by $30^0$, we get:

$$2,4,6,8,10$$
then $$3,5,7,9,11$$ and so forth until we reach $$12,2,4,6,8$$
totalling $12$ seperate layouts with this particular configuration from this.

In short, the total is the number of different configurations, including the one I've demonstrated on, multiplied by $12$ for the $12$ different numbers it can start on. See if you can go from there.

Comment: You have to be careful with this argument, which depends on the fact that there are no symmetries which would lead to double-counting. Try choosing three numbers from six - the answer is $2$ and not $6$ and the case of three from nine is not so easy. Choosing four from ten look at $1,3,6,8$. Not a problem here, but one to be aware of.